# Time varying treatment and PSM

Tags: panel-data, propensity-scores, time-varying-covariate

I am trying to create a control group using Propensity score matching for the panel dataset.

1. The issue is that treatment is time-varying.

I've read that data can be reshaped as wide format. or taken as an average across the years. 
If the treatment year is different: I want to consider three years before the treatment for each observation (corresponding years would be different for all treated observation). 
I did an extensive search and got following ideas: 1) create dummy for the treatment, and take interaction: so for the treated group: only years before the treatment have positive values and others have zero. So I can match them with other samples. OR, I checked the function: Pscore = year*10+pscore. I am not quite clear what kinds of function it would make.

Could anyone have ideas on this issue?

2. Which commands to use: There are commands: pscore, psmatch, teffect:

My question is that: for psmatch and teffect, what should be the outcome variables?

In my case, I would like to compare three (or more) dependent vars: let's say Y1, Y2, Y3. 
Then which vars should I define as an outcome vars? If I change the dep vars, then, it would change the composition of control groups?

If I want to select control groups that are only similar pre-treatment stages: X-covariates, pscore and psmatch allow not to put outcome vars. In this case control group is correctly selected?

I guess there are many cases that researchers compare results using MANY DEP VARS between pre-treatment and post-treatment. What would be the solution?